# 1 = 1 returns False in T-SQL - Why?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, sql-server-2008-r2

Please look at the snippet below

```
DEClaRE @p__linq__0 datetime
SET @p__linq__0 = '2012-02-01 00:00:00'
SELECT (STR( CAST( DATEPART (day, @p__linq__0) AS float)))
SELECT  
InvoicingActivityStartDay,
(STR(CAST( DATEPART (day, @p__linq__0) AS float))),
            CASE WHEN STR(CAST(DATEPART (day, @p__linq__0) AS float))=    InvoicingActivityStartDay THEN 'EQUAL' ELSE 'NOT EQUAL' END
FROM INVOICEMETADATA
```

This was the rough SQL Translation of a Linq-to-Entities query I had in my application. The two possible values for InvoicingActivityStartDay are 1 and 20.

This snippet results in rows like this:

```
InvoicingActivityStartDay Column1 Column2
1                         1       NOT EQUAL 
20                        1       NOT EQUAL
```

I understand why it returns NOT EQUAL for the second row; but why does it return NOT EQUAL for the first row where 1 = 1?

Comment: What is the type of `InvoicingActivityStartDay`?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi NVARCHAR(2); but holds only numbers.

Comment: Did you check that string is actually `'1'` and not `'1 '`? (note the trailing space)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes, you are correct; there are some leading and trailing spaces like this '    1          '. So instead of using SqlFunctions.StringConvert, I moved the conversion elsewhere in the code so this query gets a trimmed value. That worked. Thank you very much for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Is `InvoicingActivityStartDay` a string?  `SELECT STR(CAST(DATEPART (day, getdate()) AS float))` returns a string.  Are you expecting an integer comparison?

Comment: @Stu this should be posted as a comment not an answer.

Comment: @bluefeet – you need 50 rep to comment so that was not possible.